# Error while running ssh command in java

Tags: java, eclipse, ssh, expectj

I'm trying to run ssh command in Eclipse this way

```
ExpectJ exp = new ExpectJ();    
Spawn s = exp.spawn("ssh root@192.168.1.2");
. . . 
. . . 
. . .
```

But i get this as the error-

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

If i try doing it the following way,

```
Spawn s = exp.spawn("ssh -t -t root@192.168.1.2");
```

and execute,i get this error

```
tcgetattr: Invalid argument
```

also,the code executes only half and i get this message-

```
Killed by signal 15.
```

and finally i face a timeout exception

Any Suggestions? I'm not sure what those error messages mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use the in-built method!! Never realized that even existed.

```
s = exp.spawn(hostName, sshPort, userName, userPassword);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting the errors you're seeing, but I can say when I've needed to do ssh/scp etc. I've used this library: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ and it's worked very well for me.

Comment: so am I. I'm using jsch-0.1.44.jar

Comment: are you certain you're giving your command enough time to run? have you tried increasing the expectj timeout?

Comment: I've given 10 seconds by default. But I'll increase and check.

Comment: I increased the time out to 60 seconds and now I'm facing IOException